Errors in Altium Viewer but not in Altium Designer 24.6
I'm encountering an issue with my Altium project. When I run the project in Altium Designer, everything seems fine and I don't get any errors. However, when I open the same project in Altium Viewer, I receive three errors that are skipped, but I can't interact with them to diagnose the source of the problem.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Validated the Project in Altium Designer: No errors or warnings are shown in the Messages panel.



Checked for Hidden or Ignored Errors: Ensured that all types of messages shown in Altium Viewer are visible in Altium Designer.
Opened in Altium Viewer: The errors appear, but they are listed as "skipped" and I can't click on them to get more details.


Despite these efforts, the source of these errors remains elusive. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to proceed with identifying and resolving these errors? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

The errors you are seeing appear to be related to version control. The DRC generally doesn't pick these up unless you set a rule. Perhaps there is a design rule in viewer enabling it to check the components against version control
